# Why when a variable $x$ is small, $\log (1+ x) = x$?

Tags: econometrics

I see a conversation [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/68534/why-we-should-use-log1age-rather-than-logage?noredirect=1#comment98504_68534) that @dm63 mention that

> when Age is small, log(1+Age)=Age

I am wondering how can it happen. For example, when saying Age is small, I chose Age =1 or 2

**Age =1 => log(1+1)=log(2)=0.3 # 1**

**Age =2 => log(1+2)=log(3)=0.477 # 2**

I may fall into a fallacy, could you please help me to sort it out?
Much appreciated.

Comment: the reason why $\ln(1+x) \approx x $ when $x$ is close to $0$ is that $x$ is the the taylor polynomial of order $1$ of $\ln(1+x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you must have some faulty calculator or you are using wrong base. Natural log of 2 is about 0.7 not 0.3.

Small here means close to zero. If Age is 0 then $\ln(1+0)=0$. If Age is 0.5 (6 month old baby) the $\ln (1+0.5)= 0.41$

This is because for values of $x$ close to zero $\ln (1+x) \approx x$. But this will give you fairly good approximation only when $x<1$. For $x>1$ the error between true value and approximation quickly increases. For example $\ln (1+1) =0.7$, $\ln (1+2) =1.1$ at this point the error is already quite large.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks @1muflon1, very easy to follow. First of all, normally, I studies that log mean log10, not loge (ln), therefore I quite misunderstand. Secondly, it is now clear to me that "small" means "lower than 1" in this case.

Comment: typically in econometrics and math nowadays people use log meaning ln even though you are right by old convention $\log=\log_{10}$